# Formatting Of Timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, plsql

In my procedure I have formatted timestamp as follows

Var_Abc  varchar2 is output of the procedure

```
select to_char(max(datestamp),'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss' 
into var_Abc 
from Mytbl
```

It gives 25-apr-2011 05: 23: 45 pm

But when it is printed in Java eclipse console it's showing 23-apr-2011 11:32:34 (approx)
We are not doing any manipulation of this output var_abc.

Can somebody explain this discrepency in data from Oracle to Java output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your timestamp is a timestamp with time zone; note that the timestamp is changing exactly six hours.  What's your local GMT offset?